# How to delay audio playback to sync with FFT

Tags: c#, wpf, fft, naudio

I am using C# WPF to make a real-time FFT.

I am using NAudio's WaveIn and BufferedWaveProvider to capture any sound recorded by Stereo Mix. I take the FFT of the buffer many times per second and display it using a bitmap so that the display shows a real-time fourier transform of any audio playing through the speakers.

My problem is that, as expected, the displayed FFT lags behind the audio coming from the speakers by a small amount (maybe 200 ms).

Is there any way I can record the current audio that is supposed to be playing from the speakers so that I can perform the FFT on it and then play it back a small amount of time later (ex. 200 ms) while muting the original real-time audio.

The end result would simply be to effectively remove the perceived delay from the displayed FFT. Audio from a youtube video, for example, would lag slightly behind the video while my program is running.

Here are the relevant methods from what I have right now:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        sampleSize = (int)Math.Pow(2, 13);
        BUFFERSIZE = sampleSize * 2;

        InitializeComponent();

        // get the WaveIn class started
        WaveIn wi = new WaveIn();
        wi.DeviceNumber = deviceNo;
        wi.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(RATE, WaveIn.GetCapabilities(wi.DeviceNumber).Channels);

        // create a wave buffer and start the recording
        wi.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(wi_DataAvailable);
        bwp = new BufferedWaveProvider(wi.WaveFormat);

        bwp.BufferLength = BUFFERSIZE; //each sample is 2 bytes
        bwp.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true;
        wi.StartRecording();
    }

    public void UpdateFFT()
    {
        // read the bytes from the stream            
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFERSIZE];
        bwp.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFERSIZE);
        if (buffer[BUFFERSIZE - 2] == 0) return;

        Int32[] vals = new Int32[sampleSize];
        Ys = new double[sampleSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < vals.Length; i++)
        {
            // bit shift the byte buffer into the right variable format
            byte hByte = buffer[i * 2 + 1];
            byte lByte = buffer[i * 2 + 0];
            vals[i] = (short)((hByte << 8) | lByte);
            Ys[i] = vals[i];
        }

            FFT(Ys);
    }
```

I am still new to audio processing - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a WriteableBitmap?

Comment: @Clemens Yes and I have the WriteableBitmapEx package installed

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your delay is the latency of `WaveIn` which is about 200ms by default. You can reduce that but at the risk of dropouts.

Whilst you can capture audio being played by the system with `WasapiCapture` there is no way to change it with NAudio, or delay its playback.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mark. I'm sure you've answered this many times but how can I reduce the latency of WaveIn ? I don't see any properties of WaveIn that seem to do that.

Comment: Set `BufferMilliseconds` to a lower value